# How can I manage folders and files using rest api?

Tags: javascript, rest

How do I use rest API to pull data from folders and files? Each set of files are associated to one particular folder. I'm not sure how the are associated and I need to pull certain fields associated to the folder and another set of fields associated to the files.

Is there a way to get the a specific row of items and expand it so the children are available.

The following appear to work, but I do not see the relationship to make one or more calls and associate the folders with the files.

```
_api/web/lists/getbytitle('production_library')/items?$filter=Business_x0020_Process%20eq%27Communication%20Management%27
```

_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('production_library/Communication%20Management')

_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('production_library/Communication%20Management')/files

_api/Web/Lists(guid'85d38c8f-9ba0-426e-862e-c0497a1af706')/files('KYiffOP-8Ee2mLxLXncH7uKIVxdXGr9Ftvg6up7WivC7Rc5Eb5v8Rq9Aq-cSEEqN')/Children

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to retrieve a Folder with Files using a single request, then you could utilize the following endpoint:

GET `/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('<folder url>')?$expand=Files`

**Example**

Assume a `Documents` library that contains `Guides` folder, then the following example demonstrates how to retrieve a Folder with Files:

```
function getFolderWithFiles(webUrl,folderUrl) 
{
    var endpointUrl = webUrl + "/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('" + folderUrl + "')?$expand=Files";
    return $.getJSON(endpointUrl);
}

var webUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
getFolderWithFiles(webUrl,'Documents/Guides').done(function(folder){
    console.log(folder.Name); //print folder name
    for(var i = 0;i < folder.Files.length;i++) {
        console.log(folder.Files[i].Name); //print file name
    }

});
```

### References

[Files and folders REST API reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn450841%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Comment: For some reason a particular field or property was not showing up. You suggesting allowed me to pull that field with an addition. Now Task_x0020_Description is available at the file level.
_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('production_library/Communication%20Management')?$expand=Files/listitemallfields